# Angular Material set initial focus on form control without click event

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I am using Angular 9 and Material.  I have a Stepper that will guide users through the steps to do our workflow.

I need for the users to be able to go through the steps entirely using the keyboard, without clicking in the control.  I have seen many examples for setting focus on a control via a click event.  I don't want the users to have to click a button to set focus on the first text area.  **How can I get initial focus on the text area without the user having to click anything when the stepper is initialized?**  I have tried using the element ref in the ngAfterViewInit, but it doesn't work.  Can anyone help me understand how to do this?  Thanks.

Here is my HTML:

```
<pseudo-common-tool-header title="{{this.title}}"></pseudo-common-tool-header>
<div class="pseudo-content-manager-tool-area">
<mat-horizontal-stepper #stepper>
<mat-step [stepControl]="formGroup">
    <form [formGroup]="formGroup">
        <ng-template matStepLabel>Workstation Ids</ng-template>
        <div>
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="eris-width-45" >
            <mat-label>List of Old/New Workstations to swap (one pair per line)</mat-label>
            <textarea #wkstns rows="8" #workstations matInput placeholder="Old Workstation, New Workstation" formControlName="workstations" required></textarea>
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <div>
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline" >
                <mat-label>Soft Delete Date</mat-label>
                <input matInput #softDate [min]="minDate" [matDatepicker]="picker3" formControlName="removalDate">
                        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker3"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                        <mat-datepicker #picker3 color="primary"></mat-datepicker>
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button color="primary" #step1next mat-raised-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</mat-step>
<mat-step  label="Validate">
    <div>
        <button mat-raised-button color="secondary" matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
        <button mat-raised-button color="secondary" matStepperNext>Next</button>
      </div>
</mat-step>
<mat-step>
    <ng-template matStepLabel>Epic Build</ng-template>
</mat-step>
```

Here is my Component:

```
@Component({
 templateUrl: './swap-workstations.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./swap-workstations.component.scss']
  })

 @PseudoTool({
 title: 'Check Workstation Existence in Epic',
 componentName: 'CheckWorkstationExistenceInEpicComponent'
  })

  export class SwapWorkstationsComponent extends BasePseudoTool implements OnInit {
       formGroup: FormGroup;
    // minimum date for date picker
    minDate: Date;
 @ViewChild('wkstns') wkstns: ElementRef;
 @ViewChild('softDate') softDate: ElementRef;
 @ViewChild('step1next') step1next: ElementRef;

 constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
     super();
    }

 ngOnInit(): void {
   this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
     workstations: ['', Validators.required],
     removalDate: ['', Validators.required]
   });

// Set minimum date for date pickers.
this.minDate = new Date();
 }

 ngViewAfterInit(): void {
   this.wkstns.nativeElement.focus();
 }
```

}

Comment: You probably want to create a recursive check for when the input is ready, and focus after it is available: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49011701/focus-input-after-going-to-the-next-step-in-matstepper

Comment: @Z.Bagley  This is good stuff, pointing me toward a solution to my follow up question, which is how to specify the order of components after the initial focus is set.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ideally you would use the `autofocus` attribute but it is flakey and doesn't always work so I just create a directive that makes sure it works. I use this on forms to set focus on the first element so users can navigate the form with the keyboard.

```
import { coerceBooleanProperty } from "@angular/cdk/coercion";
import { DOCUMENT } from "@angular/common";
import {
  AfterViewInit,
  Directive,
  ElementRef,
  Inject,
  Input
} from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
  selector: "[autofocus]"
})
export class AutofocusDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  private _host: HTMLElement;
  private _focused: Element | null;
  private _autofocus = true;

  @Input()
  set autofocus(value: boolean | string) {
    this._autofocus = coerceBooleanProperty(value);
  }

  constructor(
    private readonly element: ElementRef,
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) document: HTMLDocument
  ) {
    if (typeof this.element.nativeElement.focus !== "function") {
      throw new Error("Html element must be focusable");
    }
    this._host = element.nativeElement;
    this._focused = document.activeElement;
  }

  public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    if (this._autofocus && this._host && this._host !== this._focused) {
      setTimeout(() => this.element.nativeElement.focus());
    }
  }
}
```

You can then just add the `autofocus` attribute to the textarea. This way keeps your component cleaner and it's reusable.

Comment: So you would use this just for the first element in any form, correct?

Comment: Correct but it doesn't have to be the first item. It will just set focus on the item that has the `autofocus` attribute

Comment: This is great stuff, and it answers the question I posted.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is right way to do it using `setTimeout`. Its kinda hack, i may be wrong but it does work.

```
ngViewAfterInit(): void {
   setTimeout(() => this.wkstns.nativeElement.focus());
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, Nilesh for the suggestion.  I tried this since I posted the question, and it didn't work, unfortunately.

Comment: here is the link, i tried. it did work . https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-stepper-example-e1a1dx?file=src/app/withmaterial/withmaterial.component.ts

Comment: Nilesh, I'm sorry.  I believe that it worked for you, but it didn't work for me with my situation.  My simplified example perhaps doesn't provide all the details.